# Session ID and Cookie regenerated each ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, session, url, cookies

I have created a small one page website working with ajax request.
Is not my first time I do that, but this time, the session id and the cookie are regenerated at each ajax request.

I have 2 pages: index.php and ajax.php
When I call index.php I have a session ID generated, and this ID is always the same.
But When I call ajax.php from index.php, the session ID changes at each request, and the cookies are not saved.

Here is the URL I used for the main request: http://wwww.mydomaine.com/keyword/ (keyword is something I need for my app, and I am using URL rewritting to convert the keyword in $_GET values).

And here is the URL for the ajax request: http://wwww.mydomaine.com/ajax.php

And even if I do not use the keyword, the issue is the same...

I am pretty sure that it is someting obvious, but I can point the problem...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Could you please show some code?

Comment: That sounds like a configuration issue more than a code issue, but you should still show us the javascript you use for the ajax and the php handling the request.

Comment: Did you start the session on the top of your document? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: This sounds like the scope of your session id cookie might be limited to the path `/keyword/`, which means it would not be valid for `/ajax.php` to begin with. Check what parameters you are setting that session id cookie with.

Comment: yes exactly, the "keyword" changes the path and create the issue... I have to manage url-rewritting to do all the requests with the same path ! Thanks for helping ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finaly understand !

The URL of the website is http://www.mydomaine.com/keyword/ and the url rewritting changes it in http://www.mydomaine.com?tag=keyword for my app needs.
And the ajax request are send to the url http://www.mydomaine.com/ajax.php.
And the path is not the same, that's why the session ID and the cookies are not saved !

If I change the url in http://www.mydomaine.com?tag=keyword and skip the url-rewritting and make my ajax call with the relative url ajax.php, the sessions ID and cookies are saved this time.

So If I want to keep my keyword system, I have to create a rewrite rules also for my ajax requests in order to do the requests with the same path.

Comment: … or you see to it, that your session id cookie actually gets set for the path `/` to begin with - then it is valid for the path `/ajax.php` as well.

Comment: Yes that's right, I have just change my ajax url to "/ajax" and now it is working like expecting, thanks a lot :-)